# How read json with duplicated columns via spark?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am reading json by spark there is nothing special just:

```
spark.read.option('compression', 'gzip').option('dropFieldIfAllNull', True)\
.json(source_final)
```

But it fails with `: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema`. There are no joins just 2 JSON lines in 500 Mb file have duplicated fields and entire spark job failed. Any workarounds?